# Flutter: Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add/map  multiple json objects to dart object

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=SLVO,MONY&types=stats&token=');
  /*String response = '''
 {"AAPL":
   {"stats":{"week52change":0.232986,"week52high":255.93,"week52low":142,"marketcap":1136677331400,"employees":137000,"day200MovingAvg":199.29,"day50MovingAvg":225.28,"float":4436680630.59,"avg10Volume":26482506.4,"avg30Volume":26817874.5,"ttmEPS":11.9342,"ttmDividendRate":3,"companyName":"Apple, Inc."
   }
   },
 "FB":
   {"stats":{"week52change":0.1,"week52high":255.93,"week52low":142,"marketcap":1136677331400,"employees":137000,"day200MovingAvg":199.29,"day50MovingAvg":225.28,"float":4436680630.59,"avg10Volume":26482506.4,"avg30Volume":26817874.5,"ttmEPS":11.9342,"ttmDividendRate":3,"companyName":"Apple, Inc."
   }
   }
}
  ''';*/
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
 //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String,dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic Obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  print(Obj.length);
  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  Obj.forEach((k, v,z) => photoList.add(Photo(k,v,z)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;
   String companyName;
  dynamic stats;
  //dynamic stats;
  Photo(this.symbol ,this.stats,this.companyName);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.album),
           title: Column(  children: [
             Text(photos[index].symbol),
                      Text(photos[index].companyName),
                   ],
                   ),
          subtitle: Column(
            children: [
             // Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
            //  Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
             // Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
            Text ( '${photos[index].stats["dividendYield"] ?? ""}'),
            ],
          ),
         //title: Text(photos[index].symbol),
         //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
       // subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
         // subtitle: Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Json

> > {"SLVO":{**"stats"**:{"week52change":0.047256,"week52high":7.48,"week52low":6.23,"marketcap":null,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":6.88,"day50MovingAvg":7.13,"float":null,"avg10Volume":7454.8,"avg30Volume":7927.83,"ttmEPS":null,"ttmDividendRate":null,"companyName":"Credit Suisse X-Links Silver Shares Covered Call ETN","sharesOutstanding":0,"maxChangePercent":58.7391,"year5ChangePercent":-0.4128,"year2ChangePercent":-0.1369,"year1ChangePercent":0.047256,"ytdChangePercent":-0.005789,"month6ChangePercent":0.074445,"month3ChangePercent":-0.035112,"month1ChangePercent":-0.025532,"day30ChangePercent":-0.035112,"day5ChangePercent":-0.007225,"nextDividendDate":null,"dividendYield":null,"nextEarningsDate":null,"exDividendDate":null,"peRatio":null,"beta":-0.06347545711182472},**"quote"**:{"symbol":"SLVO","companyName":"Credit Suisse X-Links Silver Shares Covered Call ETN","primaryExchange":"NASDAQ","calculationPrice":"close","open":6.89,"openTime":1574346600589,"close":6.88,"closeTime":1574370000242,"high":6.9,"low":6.87,"latestPrice":6.88,"latestSource":"Close","latestTime":"November 21,

**Added:**
&types=**stats**,quote&token

[image]

[image: Example]

error

> I/flutter (28411): Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'
>   I/flutter (28411): 71
>   I/flutter (28411): Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Comment: could you provide token to allow me to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified url to contains stats and quote 
You can not use two dynamic, its for map 
and you still need dynamic field name 
You can add token and run with full code, demo picture is as below 
code snippet

```
 Text ( '${photos[index].data["stats"]["dividendYield"] ?? ""}'),
 Text ( '${photos[index].data["stats"]["week52change"] ?? ""}'),
 Text ( '${photos[index].data["quote"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
```

demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=SLVO,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String,dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic Obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  print(responseBody);
  print(Obj.length);

  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  Obj.forEach((k, v) => photoList.add(Photo(k,v)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;
  //String companyName;
  dynamic data;
  //dynamic quote;
  Photo(this.symbol ,this.data);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.album),
          title: Column(  children: [
            Text(photos[index].symbol),
            //Text(photos[index].companyName),
          ],
          ),
          subtitle: Column(
            children: [
              // Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
              //  Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
              // Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
              Text ( '${photos[index].data["stats"]["dividendYield"] ?? ""}'),
              Text ( '${photos[index].data["stats"]["week52change"] ?? ""}'),
              Text ( '${photos[index].data["quote"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
            ],
          ),
          //title: Text(photos[index].symbol),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          // subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
          // subtitle: Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to add:stats and quote . types=stats,quote&token

Comment: full working code also fix url add quote. you can check it

Comment: If everything works well, do not forget to delete your comment have token.